# PHP/MySQL Verify Value Exists In Column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using PHP/MySQL to verify that one value exists in the column "tokencol". "$token" is the value that I want to verify and I'm sure that it has been entered properly.

Below is my code:

```
$verifytoken = mysql_query("SELECT * from tokens where tokenrow = '$token'");


if(mysql_num_rows($verifytoken) == TRUE) {
     echo "hello";
} else {
    die("Valid token not provided.");
}
```

I always get the "Valid token not provided." message instead of "hello".

What should I do to fix?
Thanks

Comment: `var_dump` or `print_r` result of query `$verifytoken` and also check what `mysql_error` says.

Comment: var_dump shows string(0) ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the database connection is ok and you have that value in the `tokens` table?

Try with `$verifytoken = mysql_query("SELECT * from tokens where tokenrow = '$token'") or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 3):

[mysql_num_rows()](https://www.php.net/function.mysql-num-rows) returns a `integer` value and not `Boolean` value.so what you was trying is basically wrong.
So try comparing with int values like this

```
if(mysql_num_rows($verifytoken) != 0) {
     echo "hello";
} else {
    die("Valid token not provided.");
}
```

also `mysql_*` functions are deprecated from `php5.5`. so try to stop using it and start using `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO`

Comment: no. if it is `== 0` means not found and `!= 0` means found. because it returns no of rows the query returns

Comment: Weird...It's now showing that the value is not found.

Comment: `$dbconnect = mysql_connect('mysqlhost', 'mysql-user', 'mysql-password', 'mysql-db');` Does it look right?

Comment: the dbconnect was correct.Make sure that you have a row in database having $token value as tokenrow value

Answer (score 0):

It's better do it like this, if you need only amount of toknes:

```
$verifytoken = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) from tokens where tokenrow = '$token'");

if(mysql_result($verifytoken, 0) > 0) {
     echo "hello";
} else {
    die("Valid token not provided.");
}
```

With `mysql_num_rows` mysql has to prepare structure for returned data and then count the result. With `COUNT` it will directly return just amount. Also, if you have for example some `tokenid` column in your table, do it like `SELECT COUNT(tokenid)...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$verifytoken = mysql_query("SELECT * from tokens where tokenrow = '$token'");
if($row_verifytoken = mysql_fetch_assoc($verifytoken))
{
    echo "hello"; 
}
else 
{
    die("Valid token not provided.");
}
```